# I am trying to implement a table in my invoice template that contains information from all products that come in my input

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

> Blockquote

<--    Below you will find my code. It displays only the information for the first product in my input. I want to display in a repeating table, information from all products.
   Secondly, in my input, you will find two prices: one for Europe and one for USA. I will like to display conditionally, under the Prices column, the price that corresponds to the current product country, determined by the country tag.  For example, if I have a product that comes from the US, I will like to take the US price, and if the product comes from Europe, I will like to display the EUR price.
   Lastly, in my code, the Total Price is displayed with NaN, what am I doing wrong?
When running my code, I am viewing this:

```
Overall, my table should be displayed as below:

 
Thank you,
Joe Doe
My Code: -->
```

> Blockquote

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Products</h2>
   
 <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#4dd2ff">
        <th>Product ID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price Per Product</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="/root/Invoices/Invoice/Products/Product/id"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="/root/Invoices/Invoice/Products/Product/name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="/root/Invoices/Invoice/Products/Product/country"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="/root/Invoices/Invoice/Products/Product/quantity"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="/root/Invoices/Invoice/Products/Product/US_price"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="/root/Invoices/Invoice/Products/Product/US_price*quantity"/></td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>









XML Input:
        
<root>
    <Invoices>
        <Invoice>
            <InvoiceProperties>
                <number>02116</number>
                <date>2016-09-10</date>
            </InvoiceProperties>
            <CustomerInformation>
                <name>Earl Library Co.</name>
                <address>1021 South Main Street,Seattle, Washington</address>
                <email>sales@earlbook.com</email>
                <telephone>(206)321-2345 </telephone>
            </CustomerInformation>
            <Products>      
                <Product> 
                    <id>1001</id>
                    <country>USA</country>
                    <name>Rendezvous with Rama by Arthur C. Clarke</name> 
                    <US_price>15</US_price> 
                    <EUR_price>20</EUR_price>
                    <quantity>3</quantity>
                    <total>45</total>
                </Product>
                <Product> 
                    <id>3237</id>
                    <country>USA</country>
                    <name>Schindler's List by Thomas Keneally</name>
                    <US_price>21</US_price>
                    <EUR_price>30</EUR_price>
                    <quantity>6</quantity>
                    <total>126</total>
                </Product>
                <Product> 
                    <id>2921</id> 
                    <country>Europe</country>
                    <name>Dune Chronicles by Frank Herbert</name>
                    <US_price>60</US_price>
                    <EUR_price>80</EUR_price>
                    <quantity>5</quantity> 
                    <total>300</total>
                </Product>
                
            </Products>
        </Invoice>
    </Invoices>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this simply like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Products</h2>
       
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#4dd2ff">
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price Per Product</th>
            <th>Total Price</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Invoices/Invoice/Products/Product"/>
        </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Product">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="country"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="quantity"/></td>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="country='USA'">
                <td><xsl:value-of select="US_price"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="US_price*quantity"/></td>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="country='Europe'">
                <td><xsl:value-of select="EUR_price"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="EUR_price*quantity"/></td>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Error"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Error"/></td>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkd

Comment: WoW! Thank's a million. You are amazing! Can I ask, is there a way that I can do this using Xpath by any chance?

Comment: No, XPath is not meant to create reports or webpages. XPath is mainly used to select elements or attributes. Like in the code above "/root/Invoices/Invoice/Products/Product" is an XPath. (It can also be used for more advanced stuff, but let's keep it at that.)

Comment: I understand. Thank you, Sir! Have a great day! :)

Comment: You're welcome. If that answers your question please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Products</h2>
       
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#4dd2ff">
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price Per Product</th>
            <th>Total Price</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Invoices/Invoice/Products/Product"/>
        </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Product">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="country"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="quantity"/></td>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="country='USA'">
                <td><xsl:value-of select="US_price"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="US_price*quantity"/></td>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="country='Europe'">
                <td><xsl:value-of select="EUR_price"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="EUR_price*quantity"/></td>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Error"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Error"/></td>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Thanks to @Sebastien
```